# Running package manager inside the docker

Tags: php, docker, composer-php

I've built an image for the purpose of PHP development, and it became clear to me that I didn't really thought about how to access the tools that I need for every day development. For example: composer, package manager for PHP, I need it to run whenever composer.json updates. I thought it is worth installing those tools inside the same image, but then I don't have a way to access them. So, I can:

1. Create separate image for composer and run it in different container
2. Install composer on my host machine.

I'd like to avoid option 2), but then, does it have sense having a setup like 1) ? How did you guys solved this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have some quite specific requirements there is a third option:

Connect to the container using [docker exec](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/exec/) command:

```
docker exec -it CONTAINER-NAME/ID COMMAND [ARG...]
```

Here is the example:

1: Create your application:

```
echo "<?php phpinfo();" > index.php
```

2: Start container:

```
docker run -it --rm --name my-apache-php-app -p 80:80 -v "$PWD":/var/www/html php:5.6-apache
```

3: Open another terminal window and exec required commands inside running container:

```
docker exec -it my-apache-php-app curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
docker exec -it my-apache-php-app ls
```

If you need shell inside running container - run:

```
docker exec -it my-apache-php-app bash
```

That's it!